# ¿Cómo debe usar el sitio un usuario interesado en crear juegos Android?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, temática

Estoy empezando a aprender Android, he visto cómo hacer aplicaciones sencillas (básicamente solo creo botones, label, etc..), pero me gustaría crear un juego, específicamente un juego de ajedrez y quería saber cuál es la mejor manera para interactuar con el sitio y la comunidad de Stack Overflow en español.

¿Cuál sería la mejor manera de obtener algún consejo de cómo hacerlo, de obtener el nombre de APIs, librerias o programas con los que pueda desarrollar un juego de ajedrez en este sitio?

Comment: [***Gorilla vs. Shark***](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Respondamos tu pregunta por partes.

Si queres obtener consejo, la mejor forma seria el chat, porque una pregunta sobre consejos podria derivar en una pregunta basada en opiniones facilmente.

Todo el resto de las recomendaciones, son justamente eso, recomendaciones y no tendrian una respuesta correcta.

Hay sitios particulares para ese tipo de cosas (por ejemplo [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)), pero desgraciadamente (o no) son en ingles.

Tal vez una pregunta puntual sobre funcionalidad puntual si funcione, pero otro tipo de preguntas, puede llegar a ser cerrada.

Comment: @shassain Lo mejor sería presentar preguntas sólidas y especificas sobre ese tema en cuanto llegues a tenerlas.  Las opiniones no son aceptadas porque no responden con certidumbre a las preguntas.